# Can't sign in to google drive (UI is blank)

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

I've just installed google drive.. but when it starts.. there is just a blank white window with no user interface.  I'm stumped.  Anyone have any ideas?  (I've tried restarting PC and uninstalling/reinstalling google drive)

Comment: May not be related, but is that a Flash interface, and is Flash installed?  Same question for Java.   Also, what browser?  I've had sites that work fine in Chrome and/or Firefox fail to render at all in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Google Drive login page uses IE core. I tried solution mentioned above and still didn't work. When I tried to open some page in IE, got blank page there also. I suddenly remembered, that I had set proxy to my virtual machine in Internet Settings x)

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs due to the problem with Internet Explorer(IE). So, any solving attempts targetting anything other than Internet Explorer will simply fail and won't resolve the issue. (e.g. installing/re-installing Google Drive). Google drive uses system's default browser i.e. IE on Windows to sign in. (not Chrome or Firefox even if you have set them as default browsers.)

If you are not able sign in through Google Drive and face a blank page, then it means that you are not able to load any webpages through the Internet Explorer either. Resolve that issue first and your Google Drive issue will be resolved automatically.

In my case, I had to downgrade my Internet Explorer version from 11 to 10. However, in your case it might be something else, but it should be definitely related to the Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today,

Ended up working after trying a few things... Don't really know what worked and why.
I didn't have any problem with IE (copying the URL from right-click>Properties and pasting it in IE displayed the login page).

Here is what I tried:

- Updating Java
- Rebooting
- Latest thing I did:

  - Quit Google Drive
  - activate compatibility mode (XP SP3) & Run google drive again
  - Launch Google drive
  - Quit google drive
  - desactivate compatibility mode
  - relaunch google drive

I'm not conviced it's somthing I did from above that made it work. But if it did, I hope it'll help others...

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved my back up and sync to another user profile on my Win 7 (I removed laptop from a domain I was no longer attached to).  I had a similar problem, where I tried to start back up and sync and received a blank window (no ability to login).  When I clicked "If having trouble, use browser to login' the browser (Chrome) would not launch.  I do not have IE installed.

My password manager was giving me a message that it could not find default browser so it finally clicked that this may be related to my Drive issue.

I reset my default browser to Chrome and am now able to login via browser to launch backup an sync.

yay!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

1. Run Internet Explorer
2. Select *Settings -> Safety -> Turn Off Windows Defender SmartScreen ...* menu item
3. In the dialog box, select *Turn Off Windows Defender SmartScreen* option and click ***OK***

Then restart Google Drive app

Answer (score 0):

1. Force to close google drive from the taskbar
2. Right-click the "Google Drive" shortcut
3. Click the properties from the menu
4. Go to the compatibility mode tab
5. Check the box "Run this program in compatibility mode for"
6. Set the Combobox to Windows 7
7. Launch the shortcut

It is done.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this issue on Win7-64 with **2FA enabled** while attempting to install Drive on my desk for the first time. The 2FA request got sent to my phone (Nexus 5x) stating that another computer was trying to sign on to my account.  I answered YES it's ok, the phone beeped and the notification went away.  *The Sign In window on the desk never acknowledged that auth*, apparently.  Fixed the issue by selecting "Try another way to sign in" then "call me".  An automated call gives you 6(?) digits to enter into the desk Sign In page, which then worked as expected.

[Screenshot of Drive Sign In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIRTG.png)

Comment: It's good to know about these alternate auth methods, but this does not answer the original question in any way.

Comment: I understood the symptom to be exactly as the original question. My solution solved the problem. I tried but couldn't get Google to fix the bug (on the phone for an hour), so this is a viable workaround (solution).

Comment: OP states that when he opens Google Drive after installing he gets a blank white window. He does not get a login window or any other interface. He would not have begun a login attempt and so even if he had 2FA the app would not have gotten to the place where it was trying authentication. So no, based on the information we currently have this is not an answer to the problem posed by OP.