# Internet Explorer 11 won't go on certain sites

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

Today i have installed google drive but i couldn't get to sign in because i had a blank sign in page. I have discovered looking on the internet that it uses IE core to show web pages (as described here: [Can't sign in to google drive (UI is blank)](https://superuser.com/questions/445958/cant-sign-in-to-google-drive-ui-is-blank) )

So i have opened Internet Explorer (which i never use) to check if something was wrong and i have discovered that it won't load content from google and other sites. 
I can go on some websites just fine, at first i thought i couldn't go on websites which had content from google (such as google analytics code) but then i realized that wasn't true.
i can go on bing, but not google (tried maps, gmail and drive) nor yahoo (tried yahoo answers too). There is a case where i can go on a site but not on a subdomain of that site (which made me first think that i couldn't reach sites with google analytics).
The page remains stuck on "Waiting for google.com" indefinitely, it won't even give me a connection timed out error or something, just keeps loading.
Chrome and Firefox work fine, IE 8 on another PC works fine, and so does IE 11 on another PC
So far I have
Checked:
- firewall (Comodo, Windows firewall is down)
- restricted sites
- hosts file
- i'm not running under a proxy
- i have Google DNS as DNS
- i have no add-ons installed on IE
- Windows update
- enanched protected mode (which wasn't enabled)

Tried:
- rebooting
- clearing cache
- Clearing cache and then rebooting
- I have even tried the "troubleshooting" functionality in the Control Panel but it couldn't find any problem
- reseting IE 11 then rebooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that the "certain sites" were sites that used a secure connection (https) or that had content coming from a secure site (such as google analytics if you use https as prefix in your code).
In "Internet Options" i went to "Content" and clicked on "Clear SSL state". This did the job

More detailed instructions can be found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967897 where it says "I can't access my bank or other secure websites"

> When you connect to a secure website, Internet Explorer uses an
>   encrypted channel that uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) technology to
>   encrypt transactions. Corrupted information in the SSL can cause
>   websites not to load correctly. Clearing the SLL state may resolve
>   this problem. To do this, follow these steps for your version of
>   Windows.   Windows 8
>
> ```
> Swipe in from the right edge of the screen (if you're using a mouse, press Windows logo key+C keys), and then tap or click Search.
> ```
>
> Enter Internet options in the search box, and then tap or click
>   Settings.
>       In the search results, tap or click Internet Options. Tap or click the Content tab, and then tap or click ClearSSL state.
>
> Windows Vista and Windows 7
>
> ```
> Click the Start button, type Internet Explorer in the search box, and then, in the list of results, click Internet Explorer.
> In Internet Explorer, click Tools, and then click Internet Options.
> Click the Content tab, and then click Clear SSL state.
> ```
>
> If clearing the SSL state does not resolve the problem, the date and
>   time settings on your PC might be incorrect. Some secure sites require
>   that the date and time on your PC match the date and time of the
>   website. To check the date and time, follow these steps for your
>   version of Windows.   Windows 8
>
> ```
> Swipe in from the right edge of the screen (if you're using a mouse, press the Windows + C keys), and then tap or click Search.
> ```
>
> Enter date and time in the search box, and then tap or click Settings.
>       In the search results, tap or click Date and Time, and then tap or click Change date and time.
>       In the Date and Time Setting window, set the current date and time.
>       Click OK, click Apply, and then click OK.
>
> Windows Vista and Windows 7
>
> ```
> In Control Panel, open Date and Time. To do this, click the Start button, type date and time in the Start Search box, and then click
> ```
>
> Date and Time in the Programs list.
>       Click Change date and time.
>       In the Date and Time Settings dialog box, set the date and time to the correct values.
>       Click OK two times.
>
> If you still can’t access secure websites, get help from the Microsoft
>   Community online.